# how to check if the OS is Windows or Debian in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I want to clear console screen every time the user make an input in C++.

I'm thinking of using system command. For Windows, it is "cls". For Linux, it is "clear". Is there a way check which system to use the appropriate command in c++?

Thanks.

Comment: if you don't want to use ifdefs, you can do them both.

Comment: @sisis: But that will dump errors to the command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

There is a trick solution:

```
if (system("clear"))
  system("cls");
```

For Unix it just working properly. For Windows, it will prompt an error like

> 'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

While it will be cleared right now by "cls". So in the Command Prompt Window, it will not leave any track. :D

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't a C++ Standards way to do it.

You can instruct your windows compiler to define the `WINDOWS` macro and your linux compiler to define the `LINUX` macro though; some compilers do this by default (for example Visual Studio defines `WIN32`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use C Preprocessor - Conditional Syntax in C++ too.

```
#ifdef linux
    //clear
#else
    //cls
#endif
```